# Store more than one record in localStorage with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a problem and dont find a solution.

I want to add more than one record in my localStorage . 
So if I enter firstname, lastname and id, and click on save, it is in my localStorage, but if I enter another one, the old entries are lost. I read in an other thread its bc of overwriting every time I call setItem, so the last one wins. It says eg use a different key (lastname1, lastname2,...). But I want just one Column Name (like in MySQL). Isn't that possible to store in localStorage like:

[image] 
?

My Sourcecode so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="fName" class="form-control" name="fName">
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lName" class="form-control" name="lName">
<input type="text" placeholder="Member Id" id="mId" class="form-control" name="mId">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="save">Save</button>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Member Id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MemberInfo(fName,lName,memberId){
        this.FirstName=fName;
        this.LastName=lName;
        this.MemberId=memberId;
    }

    $('#save').click(function () {
        $("#dataTable").find('tbody')
            .append($('<tr>')
            .append($('<td>')
            .text($('#fName').val()))
            .append($('<td>')
            .text($('#lName').val()))
            .append($('<td>')
            .text($('#mId').val()))
      );

      let angaben = { 
        firstname: $('#fName').val(),
        lastname: $('#lName').val(),
        memberid: $('#mId').val()
      }

      $('#fName').val('');
      $('#lName').val('');
      $('#mId').val('');

      localStorage.setItem("member-data", JSON.stringify(angaben));
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks for reading!

Comment: Use a key value pair, where the value is a JSON list []...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to create a collection and store it in localStorage.

For example.

```
let angaben = { 
    firstname: $('#fName').val(),
    lastname: $('#lName').val(),
    memberid: $('#mId').val()
  }

  let localData = localStorage.getItem('member-data');
  if (localData) {
      localData = JSON.parse(localData);
  } else {
   localData = [];
  }
  localData.push(angaben)
  localStorage.setItem("member-data", JSON.stringify(localData));

  // you can retrieve the data using 
  // localStorage.getItem('member-data'); and  parse it and iterate the array to render your table..
```

Comment: Oh thank you, that looks very good, like I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

1. Load and parse JSON from local storage `member-data` or create empty array if it's `null`.
2. Upon click Save:

   - push new user to `memberData` array
   - overwrite `member-data` in local storage with stringified `memberData` array

```
...

let memberData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("member-data")) || [];

$('#save').click(function () {
  ...
  memberData.push(angaben);
  localStorage.setItem("member-data", JSON.stringify(memberData));
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7jy9o30g/)

Comment: Hi dw_ it works great too, many thanks for your example and demo!